# Measures: Sigma-Additivity vs. Continuity

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $R$ be a ring of sets and $\mu$ be a positive and finite set function on $R$.

If $\mu$ is countable additive, then it is continuous from below and above:
$$A_n\uparrow A\implies \mu(A_n)\uparrow\mu(A_n)$$
$$A_n\downarrow A\implies \mu(A_n)\downarrow\mu(A_n)\quad(\mu(A_n)<\infty)$$
I managed to show continuity from below:
$$\lim_N\mu(A_N)=\lim_N\sum_{n=1}^N\mu(A_n\setminus A_{n-1})+\mu(A_0)=\mu(A)$$
however continuity from above I'm still missing; I guess exploiting:
$$A_0\setminus A=\bigsqcup_{n=0}^\infty A_n\setminus A_{n+1}$$
But how to proceed then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuity from above goes similar:
$$\lim_N\mu(A_0\setminus A_{N+1})=\lim_N\sum_{n=0}^N\mu(A_n\setminus A_{n+1})=\mu(A_0\setminus A)$$
The remaining is $\mu(B\setminus A)=\mu(B)-\mu(A)$ for $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A_n\downarrow A$, then $A_n^c\uparrow A^c$, then $\lim\mu(A_n^c)=\mu(A^c)$. As $\mu$ is finite, the measure of the universal set will be some finite $K$. Then we get $\lim(K-\mu(A_n))=K-\mu(A)$. Proved.

Comment: But it is merely a ring rather than a field...

Comment: I meant: You **cannot** use complements (otherwise it's simple).